# Sort fetched data according to date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to fetch data from mysql database in order of date with returning only 1 record from database,
if someone register today and other some minute after i want it to bring the first person details and not the other second

which approach among these two i should use?

`mysqli_query($conn,"select * from provided_user where status = '1' AND plan = '{$_SESSION['plan']}' ORDER By date_of_ph ASC LIMIT 1");`

or

```
mysqli_query($conn,"select * from provided_user where status = '1' AND plan = '{$_SESSION['plan']}' ORDER By date_of_ph DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Little explanation would be helpfull

Comment: you need to filter by day you want to retrieve info too and sort by `ORDER By date_of_ph ASC`

Comment: So you are looking for the oldest record for a given date (e.g. today) ? Not the newest record?

Comment: if i make the request i want it to show the ordest one not new one

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($conn,"select * from provided_user where status = '1' AND plan = '{$_SESSION['plan']}' ORDER By date_of_ph ASC LIMIT 1");
```

This approach will work in your current scinario as it'll fetch you all record of the date you give as a parameter in ascending order so first ever record will be return first & later later added records. By limiting it to 1 you're making sure only first record for that day will return by query. 
Good luck